# ERROR Invariant Violation: AsyncStorage has been removed from react-native core. - js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

[image]

I am continuously getting this AsyncStorage error even after using the @react-native-async-storage/async-storage, Is there any way to find out from which dependency this error is triggering.

my package.josn[dependencies]

{
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
"@react-native-community/blur": "^3.4.1",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.0.0",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.7",
"@sentry/react-native": "1.4.1",
"@tekion/tekion-base": "5.13.2",
"axios": "0.18.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.3",
"currencyformatter.js": "^2.2.0",
"dinero.js": "^1.8.1",
"fast-memoize": "^2.5.1",
"immer": "^2.0.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.11",
"lottie-ios": "3.1.8",
"lottie-react-native": "3.5.0",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.25",
"prop-types": "15.6.2",
"pusher-js": "^5.1.1",
"qs": "^6.7.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.71.0",
"react-native-blob-util": "0.17.3",
"react-native-code-push": "8.0.1",
"react-native-device-info": "10.6.0",
"react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.7",
"react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
"react-native-idle-timer": "^2.1.6",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
"react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
"react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.4.0",
"react-native-pdf": "6.4.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.1.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
"react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-version-check": "^3.4.6",
"react-native-webview": "^11.23.0",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
"react-navigation-drawer": "^1.4.0",
"react-navigation-redux-helpers": "2.0.9",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.7.3",
"react-redux": "6.0.0",
"redux": "4.0.1",
"redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
"redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
"redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
"reselect": "^4.0.0",
"tmobcomponents": "git+https://gitlab.com/myRepo/tmobcomponents#rn-sixtyone-upg-1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.0",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
"@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
"@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
"@types/react": "^18.0.24",
"@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
"babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
"babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
"eslint": "^8.19.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
"eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
"husky": "^1.3.1",
"jest": "^29.2.1",
"lint-staged": "^8.1.5",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.73.7",
"prettier": "^2.4.1",
"react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
"typescript": "4.8.4"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```js
var _reactNative = require(react-native)
exports.default = _reactNative.AsyncStorage
```

write:

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
export default AsyncStorage;
```